# Pass parameters from C# function app to another Javascript function app in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I need to set up an application in Azure and make communicate 2 functions (one written in C# and one written in JavaScript).

The C# fragment consists in analyzing a XML feed, get the data and save in objects then finally send them to the other JavaScript function by parameter.

I did read that we could establish communication between both functions using HTTP calls but is it possible to do it with parameters ?

If not, would have any suggestions in order to achieve something like this properly? I'm getting started with Azure and i don't have enough visibility to know what is recommened in such a situation

Thank you for your advices

Comment: Yes, it's possible to pass parameters to HTTP triggered function. Same as you do with any other HTTP request. Or you could put a queue in between. Do you have a specific issue?

Comment: Azure Functions and AWS Lambdas aren't. They aren't functions or lambdas, they are *HTTP services*. You call them the same way no matter what language you use - either directly through HTTP calls or by taking an action that triggers them, eg posting something to a queue or bucket

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is absolutely possible. How you do this is up to you. If you look at the default HTTP trigger templates, you can see that they take parameters (for example, as query string parameters). You can find more examples in the [HTTP and webhook recipes documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/http-and-webhooks).

You can use other trigger types for cross-function communication as well. Take a look at this documentation for related best practices: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices#cross-function-communication